# Select of Radix-UI don't display the background color of content

Tags: reactjs, select, tailwind-css, radix

```
import { ChevronDown } from 'lucide-react'
import as Select from '@radix-ui/react-select'

export default function HistoricCard() {
  return (
    <Select.Root>
      <Select.Trigger className="flex flex-row items-center gap-3 rounded-md bg-skin-fill p-2">
        <Select.Value placeholder="Projetos" />
        <Select.Icon>
          <ChevronDown className="h-5 w-5" />
        </Select.Icon>
      </Select.Trigger>
      <Select.Portal>
        <Select.Content
          align="center"
          position="popper"
          className="bg-white"
        >
          <Select.Viewport className="bg-white">
            <Select.Item value="PI">
              <Select.ItemText>Portal Interno</Select.ItemText>
              <Select.ItemIndicator></Select.ItemIndicator>
            </Select.Item>
          </Select.Viewport>
        </Select.Content>
      </Select.Portal>
    </Select.Root>
```

Even with the `bg-white` on `<Select.Content>` the color is not being applied, I also tried with the Content Demo of the documentation, but for some reason it's not working to for me.

Comment: where/how is the style rule for `bg-white` included?

Comment: It is applied to <Select.Content className="bg-white"> as shown in the Radix UI documentation and their demos. However, in this particular case, it is not functioning correctly. The same issue occurs when I copy their demo code to my own repository.

Comment: can you share the link to the example page? or code example?

Comment: here you can see the import of the stylesheet, do you have something similar?

https://www.radix-ui.com/primitives/docs/components/select#with-disabled-items